# jcarousel Item scroll visible item on how to add add class first and last

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

i have using  [http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel slider](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel%20slider).

I have display 3 images on one slide on click slide 1 image.

I want visibale item list on add class first and last.
All ready i have add first class visible current item using targetout event but how to add class on visiable last item .

```
var jcarousel1 = $('.jcarousel1');

jcarousel1.on('jcarousel:targetin', 'li', function() {
    $(this).addClass('first');
})
jcarousel1.on('jcarousel:targetout', 'li', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('first');
})
```

[See Hear](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/741)

Answer (score 0):

Get current item index value then add current index in increment value for add class.

```
var jcarousel1 = $('.jcarousel1');

jcarousel1.on('jcarousel:targetin', 'li', function() {
    $( ".jcarousel1 li" ).eq($(this).index() + 2).addClass('last');
    $(this).addClass('first');

});
jcarousel1.on('jcarousel:targetout', 'li', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('first');
    $( ".jcarousel1 li" ).eq($(this).index()+ 2).removeClass('last');
});
```